# Как вывести переменную net через print после цикла(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
weights = []
for i in range(15):
    weights.append(0)

bias = 7

def proceed(number):
    net = 0
    for i in range(15):
        net += int(number[i]) * weights[i]
```

Comment: `print(net)` / `print("net:", net)` / `print("net: '{}'".format(net))`

Answer (score 0):

```
def proceed(number):
    net = 0
    for i in range(15):
        net += int(number[i]) * weights[i]
    print(net)

# При вызове напечатает
proceed(number)
# net
```

Можно возвращать значение из функции:

```
def proceed(number):
    net = sum([int(number[i]) * weights[i] for i in range(15)])
    return net

print(proceed(number))
# net
```